# File access exception when trying to open file after closing and re-opening program

Tags: c#, exception, file-access

I seem to have a problem with some code which is used to change a user's password for software. if you run the software and change the password, it will succeed first time, however, if the user then logs out (which restarts the software), then tries to change their password again, a file access exception is thrown.

How can this be the case as the software has been restarted?

code:

```
void ChangePassword()
    {
        string UserDataBaseString = File.ReadAllText("UserData.txt");
        string[] UserDataBase = File.ReadAllLines("UserData.txt");
        if (UserDataBaseString.Contains(MD5Hash(NewPassworTxBx.Text)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("That password is already in use");
        }
        else
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i != UserDataBase.Length)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(UserDataBase[i]);
                if (UserDataBase[i].ToString() == GlobalVar.UserNameEntered.PadRight(20, ' ') + MD5Hash(CurrentPasswordTxBx.Text))
                {

                    string usr = UserDataBase[i].Substring(0, 20);
                    string input = usr + MD5Hash(NewPassworTxBx.Text);
                    UserDataBase[i] = input;
                    MessageBox.Show(UserDataBase[i].ToString());
                    //File.WriteAllLines("UserData.txt", UserDataBase);
                    int i1 = 0;

                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter("UserData.txt", false))
                    {
                        while (i1 != UserDataBase.Length)
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(UserDataBase[i1]);
                            i1 = i1 + 1;
                        }
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("Password changed to: " + NewPassworTxBx.Text);
                    break;
                }
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated, but are you aware that is a very insecure way to hide logins?

Comment: Can you share the exception stack?

Comment: i know that its an insecure way to hide logins, the software is for coursework, so i'm only implementing basic security such as hashing passwords.

Comment: with regard to the exception, i guess if i can attach the VS debugger to the process once it restarts (since logging out closes and re-opens the program). I'll see what i can do